# nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf images not working on laravel

Tags: pdf, laravel

I've included the package, the pdf gets generated but somehow the images dont appear on the pdf. The HTML content and CSS works like expected.

**When i return the view as how you'd normally return a view in laravel, the receipt displays nicely along with the images**.

But when i:

`return PDF::html('receipt.show', $data);`

The images dont appear.

My view file has the image like so:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/receipt/banner.jpg">
```

The image is within:

```
public/img/receipt/banner.jpg
```

This is a laravel app running on homestead environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use absolute path in image `src` attribute instead of relative. Smth like:

```html
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://your-domain.com/img/receipt/banner.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<base href="http://your-domain.com/" />
```

into your head and it will help for all your links